# R function dbGetQuery error embedded nul string

Tags: sql, r, oracle

I have a query from oracle and I am using dbGetQuery in R to get the same result of Oracle in R.
But I have the following error:
"embedded nul string: 'JOY\0NOSTALG".

Infact, there is record in my data that contain JOYNOSTALG, and if filter-out that record R start again to work.

Now I do not understand how to solve the problem in order to have also all the records that have JOYNOSTALG.

Thank you,
Andrea

Comment: It seems that JOYNOSTALG contains `\0` termination character. Have you tried replacing JOY\0NOSTALG with JOYNOSTALG ?

Comment: hi I checked it with notepad++ and is writen like: JOYNULNOSTALG, so there is a NUL between JOY and NOSTLAG and R do not like it... I can not replace it because I am querying in R form Oracle DB and I can not modify the DB... Do you have a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

[This webpage](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4106681) had a solution that worked for me:

You need to replace the NUL with an space or empty string to be able to pull this data in.  So do the following with your SQL code:

```
dat <- dbGetQuery(myConnection,"SELECT REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, CHR(0), ' ') AS NEW_COLUMN
                                FROM MY_TABLE")
```

Hope this helps you.